# Opening .eml files with mutt

Tags: mutt, email

How should one open .eml files in linux ? I'm not sure if `mutt` can handle it ?

**UPDATE**

I worked it out partially , by creating a new mailbox:

`mkdir -p a/{cur,tmp,new}`

And place the eml file in a/cur , I could read it with:

`mutt -f`

But that's not exactly what I want yet

Comment: If your editor is set to `vim` in mutt, don't they get opened as plain text? You could also set an entry in `mailcap` to open them with your text editor if they are attachments.

Comment: @warl0ck Are you tested what mentioned in answers before editing the question?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

mutt doesn't seem able to open individual messages. What you can do is convert the .eml file into an mbox folder containing a single message. This basically involves adding a `From` line at the top, which can be done using `formail -b`:

```
formail -b < themessage.eml > themessage.mbox
```

This can then be opened within mutt using `change-folder` (default key `c`).

Comment: Nice answer.  I would also add that the message could be opened directly on the command line:  `mutt -f themessage.mbox`

Also, the formail command is part of the procmail package, if you don't have it already installed on your system (debian-based systems, at least).

Comment: formail is found in the procmail package

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.  Thanks for the "formail -b" suggestion.

The following mailcap entry seems to eliminate the necessity of manual saving, running "formail -b", and changing to the mailbox.  These three steps are reduced to pushing `<enter>` on the message/rfc822 attachment in the attach view:

`message/rfc822; formail -b < %s > %s.mbox && mutt -f '%s.mbox'; needsterminal`

Additional advantage is that the .mbox file is created in `/tmp` directory and does not require clean-up afterwards.